# Python rounding numpy array entries down to the nearest whole number. How can I fix this?

Tags: python

Bear with me as I'm not very experienced with coding, but an example of my problem is as follows:

I define a matrix V as below and then attempt to scale the first row by a factor equal to the first entry in V:

```py
V=np.array([[3,1],[1,3]])
V[0]=V[0]/V[0,0]
print(V)
```

```
Output:
[[1 0]
 [1 3]]
```

For some reason, Python has rounded the scaled entries down to the nearest whole number. Another example:

```py
V=np.array([[3,1],[1,3]])
print(V[0]*1.8)
```

```
Output:
[5.4 1.8]
```

There seems to be no issue, but when I assign the first row of V equal to the
scaled version the same problem arises.

```py
V=np.array([[3,1],[1,3]])
V[0]=V[0]*1.8
```

```
Output:
 [[5 1] 
 [1 3]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[5.4 1.8],
[1 3]]
```

Clearly, the output should have `[5.4 1.8]` as the first row, but Python has rounded each entry down to the nearest whole number.

Why is Python doing this? What am I doing wrong?

Problem outlined completely above, not much to say here.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2):

This is because your numpy array is `int`. ALL elements in the numpy array must be the same type. So when you multiply by a `float` your array, the array remains as an `int` (no decimals)

You need to convert your array to `float` first in order to get the output you expect.

```
V=np.array([[3,1],[1,3]]).astype('float')
V[0]=V[0]*1.8
```

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, you've solved my problem!

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this is the solution, please mark it as it. Thanks!

Comment: If you think this is the solution to your question, please mark it as the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: You could also just use `np.array([[3.0, 1.0],[1.0, 3.0]])` if you wanted to skip the `astype` call